# The limit of a singular matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, banach-spaces

Now to show the set of invertible $n \times n$ matrices are an open set in the set of all $n \times n$ matrices one can show the set of singular matrices are closed in the set of all $n \times n$ matrices.  Therefore if $A_n$ is a sequence of singular matrices that converge to say $B$ then $B$ must be a singular matrix.  I am having trouble trying to show this though.  So assuming we have a normed vector space $$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||A_n-B||=0.$$  I guess I need to show $\det(A_n-B)=0$ for $n\ge N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you probably know that the pre-image of a closed set under a continuous map is closed. Consider the determinant as a function from the space $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ of all $n\times n$ matrices to the real numbers. I.e. $$ \det:\mathbb R^{n^2}\to \mathbb R.$$

This is a continuous function because the determinant is just a polynomial in the entries of the matrices. The singular matrices as you know are the pre-image of the set $\{0\}$ which you know is closed in $ \mathbb R$. So the singular matrices are closed in the space of all $n\times n$ matrices as well.

Edit: Note that this proof is not unique to matrices over $\mathbb R$ but any topological ring $R$, i.e a ring with a topology such that addition and multiplication  are continuous functions with respect to this topology. Thanks to user1551 for setting me straight.

Comment: I am puzzled by your edit. If we are talking about a general field $K$ (or strictly speaking, the scalar field of any finite-dimensional normed vector space --- there are examples of discontinuous linear maps if the space is infinite-dimensional), is the continuity of polynomials really an obvious fact?

Comment: @user1551 But the space of $n\times n$ matrices over a field $K$ is always $n^2$ dimensional (i.e. finite). You can take the usual basis consisting of matrices that are $1$ in the $(i,j)$th place and zero elsewhere. And for this finite dimensional space, the polynomials are continuous  because the functionals taking a matrix to it's $(i,j)$th element is continous and the standard real analysis argument that products and sums of continuous functions are continuous. Right?

Comment: How? Textbook proofs for the continuity of real polynomials usually make use of the fact that $+:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ and $\times:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ are continuous, and this fact is usually proved with explicit use of the Euclidean topology. How does this carry over to a general field $K$?

Comment: @user1551 Six years later, I realize that you are absolutely right. We need $K$ to be a topological ring. Thank you.